# _TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String') firebase firestore

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, dart-null-safety

I am trying to retrieve data from my cloud firestore but it keeps returning a type error.
This is the code for firestore

```
    await firestore
    .collection('users')
    .where("email", isEqualTo: _search.text)
    .get()
    .then((value) {
  if (value.docs.isNotEmpty) {
    setState(() {
      userMap = value.docs[0].data();
      isLoading = false;
    });
  }
```

This is where the error "_TypeError (type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String')" occurs

```
                      ListTile(
                    onTap: () {},
                    title: Text(
                      userMap["name"],
                      style: const TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    subtitle: Text(userMap["email"])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Text` widget doesnt accept null value, you can provide default value on null cases like

```dart
Text(userMap["name"]??"got NUll",)
```

Comment: More about [Text](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/ui/widgets/text)